# How to transform a Plot or a ParametricPlot into a Region

Tags: regions

I can get a `Region` from a `Graphics` like this:

[image: Graphics]

But how can I transform the graphics in a `Plot` or a `ParametricPlot` into a `Region`?

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`ParametricRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion.html) instead of `Plot`/`ParametricPlot` to obtain an exact region.  Alternatively use [`DiscretizeGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeGraphics.html) on the output of `Plot`/`ParametricPlot` to approximate it as a region.

Comment: Oh~Thinks a lot.